# Cannot Bind Value to Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, bind, datatextfield

Why can't I binding value to the dropdownlist? It always return message: `DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'.`

I have a dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Parameter_Dropdownlist" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Then on code-behind:

```
If myCEConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
    Try
        myCEConnection.Open()
    Catch
        Return
    End Try
End If

Dim reader As SqlCeDataReader
Dim myCommand As SqlCeCommand = myCEConnection.CreateCommand()

myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Name, Code FROM Room"
reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()

DT.Load(reader)

DDL.DataSource = DT
DDL.DataTextField = DT.Columns("Name").ColumnName.ToString()
DDL.DataValueField = DT.Columns("Code").ColumnName.ToString()
DDL.DataBind()

myCEConnection.Close()
```

How can I bind the value to the dropdownlist? Please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, adding example :-

```
If myCEConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
   Try
      myCEConnection.Open()
  Catch
      Return
  End Try
End If

Dim reader As SqlCeDataReader
Dim myCommand As SqlCeCommand = myCEConnection.CreateCommand()

myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Name, Code FROM Room"
reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()

DT.Load(reader)

DDL.DataSource = DT
DDL.DataTextField = DT.Columns(0).ColumnName.ToString()
DDL.DataValueField = DT.Columns(1).ColumnName.ToString()
DDL.DataBind()

myCEConnection.Close()
```